# react-native-video TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

So I tried using react-native-video package from npm to play a youtube video:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Video
          source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swigQ10SL_w'}}
          style={{ width: 800, height: 800 }}
          muted={true}
          repeat={true}
          resizeMode={"cover"}
          volume={1.0}
          rate={1.0}
          ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By using `npm`, install `react-native-video` package to your `react-native` project.

```
npm install --save react-native-video
```

Link the package to platforms `iOS` and `android` with

```
react-native link
```

[image]

To link library on `iOS`, if they are not linked already do next steps:

- In `XCode` project navigator, right click on `Libraries` folder and choose `add files to projectname` option then go to `node_modules/react-native-video/ios/` and choose `RCTVIdeo.xcodeproj`
- Go to `targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` hit `+` and choose `libRCTVideo.a`

**Strict Note:**

Don't play `youtube` video in `react-native-video` as there is no issue in the code, instead you can try this.
http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4

For `youtube` videos

```
npm install react-native-youtube-player@latest --save
```

Or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube