# Problem: Vimeo player full screen does not work in a single tab in my react native mobile app

Tags: react-native, vimeo, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

"Fullscreen" and "Exit fullscreen" buttons didn't work as expected. It works only after multiple clicks. When first clicked it shows a tooltip. Subsequent recursive clicks it opens some time.

I'm using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vimeo-iframe

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Its better to used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708882/9108471) method with `react-native-video` package. Because other video players are difficult to maintain or customize later on.